# SQLITE3 Error: "SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range"

Tags: sql, sqlite

### I'm trying to search for a user by a string so kind of like autocompletion

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%?%" LIMIT 25;
```

And it gives me this error:
`SQLITE_RANGE: column index out of range`

I looked into a bunch of github issues but couldn't find any that works for me. 
In the SQLite CLI it works, so I have no idea why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please read this article about [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you improve your question and get good answers faster.

Answer (score 5):

A `?` inside a string like `"%?%"` is not considered as a placeholder for the parameter that you pass, which throws the error that you get because the parameter has no where to be placed in the statement.

Use concatenation of the `?` with the wildcards:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE "%" || ? || "%" LIMIT 25;
```